# Problems with GLEW and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glew

In short, my program using GLEW and compiled with VS2013 crashes when calling an OpenGL function.

Here's what I did:

Downloaded latest version of GLEW from their website.

Created an empty project in VS 2013

Added glew32s.lib; opengl32.lib; glu32.lib to linker input;

Added main.cpp with the following code (note that I did define GLEW_STATIC)

```
#include <windows.h>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

int main() {
    GLuint s = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    return 0;
}
```

It builds with the following linker warnings:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>glew32s.lib(glew.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc100.pdb' was not found with 'glew32s.lib(glew.obj)' or at 'D:\javadyan\Code\tinygamelib_demo\Project1\Debug\vc100.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
```

When I run the program it crashes as soon as it hits the `glCreateShader` call.

Such problems didn't happen in VS2012

Has anyone tried to use GLEW with VS2013? Did you run into something similar and how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a problem of C run time mixed version.
1. When you were building your dll with VS2012, which `Platform Toolset` were you using?  Can you use this same version of `Platform Toolset` with VS2013?
2. Also it may be worth checking the `Runtime Library` (debug/release, static/dynamic) and comparing their values between your VS2012 and VS2013 projects.

Comment: Turns out I simply forgot to properly initialize GLEW. The link warnings were an unrelated problem, I changed my runtime library to multithreaded DLL (/MD) and they were gone. You did help me with that part of the question, so Im accepting your answer :)

Comment: @Grigory thanks for accepting and taking the time to detail your actions ;)